# Wireless not working with Intel Wireless PRO 3956ABG on Inspiron 1525 with 14.04

Tags: wireless, dell, intel

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop, and I found that Camera, CD drive adn wireless cards are not working

---

Wireless card is displayed by running "lspci"

```
0b:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)

Below is the output of ifconfig -a

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1d:09:50:5d:d5  
          inet addr:192.168.0.4  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21d:9ff:fe50:5dd5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:92788 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:65830 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:107595122 (107.5 MB)  TX bytes:8124966 (8.1 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3637 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:352356 (352.3 KB)  TX bytes:352356 (352.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1f:3c:27:6d:7d  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

I could not see enable wifi option as it is grayed out.

Kindly suggest what settings I need to change, I am a first time linux user.

Thanks in advance.

---

Also I could see that it is disabled:

```
*-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 02
       serial: 00:1f:3c:27:6d:7d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=4.2.0-36-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:29 memory:fe7ff000-fe7fffff
```

Answer (score 0):

Saying it's not working might mean thousands of reasons and things to check, but first of all, I would check whether it's a problem with config or missing device at all.
Try to execute below two commands from Terminal, as sudo or root user - "lspci" and "ifconfig -a", both without quotes. If lspci doesn't list your card (read precisely every row to search for Intel or network or wifi strings), but ifconfig commands shows it, then you might have problems only with proper configuration for wifi (or parameters for wifi driver module)